# Did Shadowfax go to Valinor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I seem to recall that Shadowfax was taken with Gandalf to Valinor, but I have not been able to find a clear reference in the Lord of the Rings. Is there any writing by Tolkien adressing this question?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Tolkien wrote on this subject in a letter to a fan. It was his belief that Shadowfax did indeed travel with Gandalf, despite it not being mentioned specifically.

> ***I think Shadowfax certainly went with Gandalf [across the Sea], though
> this is not stated. I feel it is better not to state everything (and
> indeed it is more realistic, since in chronicles and accounts of
> ‘real’ history, many facts that some enquirer would like to know are
> omitted, and the truth has to be discovered or guessed from such
> evidence as there is).** I should argue so: Shadowfax came of a special
> race (II 126, 129, III 346) being as it were an Elvish equivalent of
> ordinary horses: his ‘blood’ came from ‘West over Sea’. It would not
> be unfitting for him to ‘go West’. Gandalf was not ‘dying’, or going
> by a special grace to the Western Land, before passing on ‘beyond the
> circles of the world’: he was going home, being plainly one of the
> ‘immortals’, an angelic emissary of the angelic governors (Valar) of
> the Earth. He would take or could take what he loved. Gandalf was last
> seen riding Shadowfax (III 276). He must have ridden to the Havens,
> and it is inconceivable that he would [have] ridden any beast but
> Shadowfax; so Shadowfax must have been there. A chronicler winding up
> a long tale, and for the moment moved principally by the sorrow of
> those left behind (himself among them!) might omit mention of the
> horse; but had the great horse also shared in the grief of sundering,
> he could hardly have been forgotten.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Tolkien: Letter 268](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_268)</sup></sub>

Comment: So the lord of all horses abandonded the rest of horse-kind, leaving them no lord? Who might have been Shadofax's successor? Arod, who allowed his rider to die?